Как создать десктопное приложение для перепрошивки микроконтроллера с пользовательским интерфейсом?
Делаю кулон с матрицей светодиодов, на котором будут проигрываться разные анимации. Надо сделать приложение на компьютер для создания своих анимаций, которое будет перепрошивать микроконтроллер (в моем случае Attiny1616), а также чтобы был удобный интерфейс с помощью которого можно будет сделать анимацию покадрово. Так как в C# я мало что знаю, подскажите с чего начать, что может понадобиться, стоит ли это вообще делать на C#.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

я бы делал на winforms. из плюсов: 1) интуитивно понятен новичку, легко начать делать приложения, 2) модель холста, можно накидать цветные кружки, есть видос, 3) доступна интеграция с си (си++) библиотеками, надо сразу подумать, как будете управлять устройством

@АлексейОбухов 3) она доступна везде, в целом в .NET и её наличие от выбранного UI не зависит (исключение - WinRT/UWP, там есть ограничения, но мы их не рассматриваем). Interop называется. 2) цветных кружков накидать в XAML с привязкой к данным задача 5 минут. 1) ловушка новичка, взять с лёгким порогом вхождения и мучаться когда потребуется что-то посложнее, или взять сразу полноценный мощный гуй, но потратить чуть больше времени на знакомство? Дилемма

Рекомендую вам зайти в свой профиль и завершить регистрацию аккаунта, сейчас она не полная.
